# modal o alerta de error no se puede eliminar

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo una tabla a la cuál si presiono el botón de eliminar me manda un modal, y tengo un php donde esta la consulta delete, mi problema es que está consulta puede que no se elimine porque si hay cierto parámetro como puedo mandar un mensaje de error de que no se puede eliminar.
Este es mi index:

```html
<td>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <button type='button' class="btn btn-link" onclick="javascript:eliminar(<?=$id;?>);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>            
 </td>
 
<div id="delete" class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <form method="post">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">       
                            ¿Está seguro de que desea eliminar?
                        </div>
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Eliminar" id="btn-eliminar">Si, eliminar</button>
</div>
```

Y este es mi php en algunos casos si se puede eliminar ya que el id_accion debe ser null pero si no, como puedo mandar un mensaje de error no se puede eliminar, ocupo ajax

```html
<?php

require '../../../../config/db.php';
$sql2 = "delete from accion where id=? and id_accion IS NULL";
$stmt2 = $conexion->prepare($sql2);
$stmt2->bind_param("i", $_POST['id']);
$stmt2->execute();
$stmt2->close();
?>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir lo que tienes en la línea 156 de tu código? Según el error, hay un "<" que sobra

Comment: disculpa pero como veo la linea 156 en stackoverflow?

Comment: Hola @ricardo Como no puedes mostrar otro dialogo mientras tengas el modal activo puedes incrustar en el un pequeño div vacío que muestre el estatus de la respuesta reemplazando su atributo 'innerhtm' con el mensaje que necesites sacandolo de la que devuelva el servidor.

Comment: ok pero es que realmente necesito que aunque el usuario presione "si, eliminar", salga un modal o alerta de no se puede eliminar si no se pudo realizar el delete

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar transation de mysql https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.begin-transaction.php

```
 $mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "mi_usuario", "mi_contraseña", "sakila");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
printf("Conexión fallida: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
printf("Conexión fallida: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
exit();
 }

 $mysqli->begin_transaction(MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_ONLY);

 $mysqli->query("SELECT first_name, last_name FROM actor");
$mysqli->commit();

$mysqli->close();    exit();
}

$mysqli->begin_transaction(MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_ONLY);

$mysqli->query("SELECT first_name, last_name FROM actor");
 $mysqli->commit();

 $mysqli->close();
```